# Setting class on ion-item when using *ngFor

Tags: angular

I am using the following *ngFor loop. Within the response I get back tag.style - this is the class I want to apply to the ion-item row. This code doesn't work - after the first item in the loop it seems to stop.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let tag of tags" (click)="selectTag(tag)" class="{{ tag.style }}">
        {{ tag.name }} ({{ tag.style }})
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

How can I set the class of ion-item to be tag.style?

Comment: `[ngClass]="tag.style"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let tag of tags" (click)="selectTag(tag)" [ngClass]="tag.style">
        {{ tag.name }} ({{ tag.style }})
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```